# Reduce amount of triangles and then map color onto model

Tags: meshlab

I'm very new to meshlab and am not much of a programmer, so this is a shot in the dark.

I have a 3D model of the inside of a very [intricate building](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYsjw.jpg) with many 3D sculptures. Around 2000 photos were taken to create this 3D model.
Right now there are about 6 million vertices and 12 million faces. I need to drastically cut down on the number of [triangles in the model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sglei.png), without compromising on all of the colors/patterns (texture?).
I've been told there should be a way to reduce the amount of triangles and then adding the colors back onto the surface as a texture. Or at least on flat surfaces, the amount of triangles can be drastically decreased, and then afterwards you should be able to slap on a texture of the original colors.

I've looked in the filters > texture menu, but I can't seem to figure out what to do.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is [mesh simplification](https://help.sketchfab.com/hc/en-us/articles/205852789-MeshLab-Decimating-a-model), the tool is in:
`Filters` -> `Remeshing, Simplification and Reconstruction` ->
`Simplification: Quadric Edge Collapse Decimation (with texture)`